# AngularJS, Wordpress and Native App

Tags: wordpress, api, angularjs, mobile, buddypress

I am going to build a social intranet for a company with about 750 employees. They already use WordPress with the BuddyPress plugin. Also, they have multiple internal systems which would have to supply additional data for the intranet. The application has to available for PC, and smartphone/tablet via browser and as a standalone app. Both for at least Android and iOS.

So far, we've been talking about building a responsive HTML5 webapp which communicates with a centralized API. I would have to build the API, too. 
For the frontend they've recommended me to use AngularJS, but I'm concerned about performance if you combine it with WordPress/BuddyPress. Does anyone have experience with this? And would you build a responsive website or a seperate mobile version?

I've been comparing multiple solutions to build the mobile app with (near) native performance. These are some viable options I've found:

- Appcelerator Titanium Studio
- AppGyver Steroids
- Xamarin Studio

In your experience, what are the pros and cons with these options? Are there any pitfalls with any of these? Do you have other recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that Wordpress / Buddypress in combination with AngularJS should cause any performance issues.

There are basically two aspects of the app which you're involving here. The server-side, which is running Wordpress, and then the client-side which is running AngularJS.

In any case, if you have queries on a huge DB, or a slow server, or a series of recursive queries, you will experience performance issues on the server-side with Wordpress, which might result is slow load times. In any case, if you have many DOM items displaying on the client-side, with complex CSS styling, you may experience some performance issues on the client-side, especially with older smart-phones, which might result in a slow/choppy UX experience.

There are some client-side performance implications with AngularJS when using `ng-repeat` when you get into objects with hundreds of sub-objects and deep data binding, which could easily cause some client-side performance issues.

I've been using Wordpress / AngularJS together for a year developing web apps intended for use on all the prescribed platforms, and there's no perceivable performance issues - certainly if there were any, I can't see how it would be caused by the Wordpress/Buddypress and AngularJS combo, since they're handling completely different sides of the app.